# Php error exception

Tags: php, sqlite, исключения, sqlite3

```
try {
    $db = new SQLite3('wrong');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    printf('Error! %s.', $e->getMessage());
}
//Error! Unable to open database: unable to open database file.
```

но если

```
try {
  $db = new SQLite3('real.db');
  $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM wrong');
} catch (Exception $e) {
  printf('Error! %s.', $e->getMessage());
}
//Warning: SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, no such table: wrong in /home/...
```

Почему в случае отсутствующей таблицы ошибка не перехватывается?

Comment: Потому что функция `query` не выбрасывает исключение, которое можно отловить.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Исключения не будет, в этом случае функция query вернет FALSE, поэтому:

```
$result=$db->query('SELECT * FROM wrong');
if($result===FALSE)
{
  printf('Error!');
}
```